# Getting the value of a specific input from a list of inputs with the same class

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, twig

So, I've looked a lot into this and couldn't really find an answer that suited my needs or addressed my issue.

I have a block of html `<div>`, `<span>`, `<i>` and `<input>` that I generate multiple times with a for loop (amount generated corresponds to how many rows I have in a table in my database).

Naturally, all of them have the same class.
Now I want the value a specific  that's associated to its corresponding `<i>` or `<span>` or `<div>`, meaning that is basically in that one specific block that corresponds to a row in my database.

This is the block that's being generated from within a for loop (its in twig but I don't think that's of any relevance)

```
{% for coach in coaches %}
        <div>
            <span></span>
            <span class="rating" data-rating="0">
                <i class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="1">&#9733;</i>
                <i class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="2">&#9733;</i>
                <i class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="3">&#9733;</i>
                <i class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="4">&#9733;</i>
                <i class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="5">&#9733;</i>
            </span>
            <span>
                <input class="coach-id" hidden value="{{ coach.id }}">
            </span>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here's how I'm getting the value of the `<input>` in js

```
        const coach_id = document.querySelector('.coach-id').value;
```

Now I'm using this value in a url like this

```
           let url = `/coach/editRating/${coach_id}/${note}`
            window.location.href = url
            console.log(url)
```

But this will always give me the value of the `<input>` with `coach_id = 1`

What can I do to get the specific value associted with a specific `<span class="rating" data-rating="0">` ?

EDIT!!!

So using @Blunt Jackson 's answer, I tried the following

```
            var coach_ids = document.getElementsByClassName("coach-id");
            for (var i = 0; i < coach_ids.length; i++) {
                var val = coach_ids[i].getAttribute['data-note'];
                let url = `/coach/editRating/${val}/${note}`
                window.location.href = url
                console.log(url)
            }
```

But val's value is undefined. I'm probably doing something wrong

2nd EDIT!!!

So, basically I have these  that represent stars, once you click on one you get the value of the star you clicked. I don't have an issue with the value of the star.
I want to get the value of the  that's within that same  as the . The reason for this is because I have multiple  blocks and they all have the same content in html but the values I'm getting from the database aren't the same. So each  would correspond to a row in a table in my database. I need to access the specific  value because it correlates to the rating I'm trying to update in the database.

Script responsible for the stars and posting the parameters

```
const ratings = document.querySelectorAll('.rating');
        const session_id = document.querySelector('.session-id').value;
        ratings.forEach(rating =>
            rating.addEventListener('mouseleave', ratingHandler)
        );
        const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.rating .star');
        stars.forEach(star => {
            star.addEventListener('mouseover', starSelection);
            star.addEventListener('mouseleave', starSelection);
            star.addEventListener('click', activeSelect);
        });
        function ratingHandler(e) {
            const childStars = e.target.children;
            for(let i = 0; i < childStars.length; i++) {
                const star = childStars.item(i)
                if (star.dataset.checked === "true") {
                    star.classList.add('hover');
                }
                else {
                    star.classList.remove('hover');
                }
            }
        }
        function starSelection(e) {
            const parent = e.target.parentElement
            const childStars = parent.children;
            const dataset = e.target.dataset;
            const note = +dataset.note; // Convert note (string) to note (number)
            for (let i = 0; i < childStars.length; i++) {
                const star = childStars.item(i)
                if (+star.dataset.note > note) {
                    star.classList.remove('hover');
                } else {
                    star.classList.add('hover');
                }
            }
        }
        function activeSelect(e) {
            const parent = e.target.parentElement
            const childStars = parent.children;
            const dataset = e.target.dataset;
            const note = +dataset.note; // Convert note (string) to note (number)
            for (let i = 0; i < childStars.length; i++) {
                const star = childStars.item(i)
                if (+star.dataset.note > note) {
                    star.classList.remove('hover');
                    star.dataset.checked = "false";
                } else {
                    star.classList.add('hover');
                    star.dataset.checked = "true";
                }
            }
            const noteTextElement = parent.parentElement.lastElementChild.children.item(0)
            noteTextElement.innerText = `Note: ${note}`;
            console.log(note);
            let url = `/session/sessionRating/${session_id}/${note}`
            window.location.href = url
            console.log(url)
```

Comment: Am I right to assume that `data-checked` gets set to `true` after clicking a star?

Comment: @DarkBee I updated the question to include all the js responsible for the stars, and yes your presumption is well placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things missing in your example, but I'll address the base question:

"What can I do to get the specific value of an item within the span-class-"rating"?"

The easy way is write the sequence with an id as well as a class. E.g.,

```
    <div>
        <span></span>
        <span class="rating" data-rating="0">
            <i id="star1" class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="1">&#9733;</i>
            <i id="star2" class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="2">&#9733;</i>
            <i id="star3" class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="3">&#9733;</i>
            <i id="star4" class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="4">&#9733;</i>
            <i id="star5" class="star" data-checked="false" data-note="5">&#9733;</i>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input class="coach-id" hidden value="{{ coach.id }}">
        </span>
    </div>
```

Since you are using a for loop to generate the list, you can dynamically assign each a unique class id, and then identify each element individually.

Perhaps a better way, depending on our underlying design: assuming these items are in some way interactive, you can add a separate onclick event to each item such that whatever action happens is passing the dom element to the handler.

Here's an approach that may not work with all browsers:

```
var element = document.querySelector('["data-note"="3"]');
```

I've never done that one myself, it's rumored to be slow.

Finally, probably the worst way, you can iterate the class, like so:

```
var stars = document.getElementsByClassName("star");
for (var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    var val = stars[i].getAttribute['data-note'];
    // do something with val.
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I tried the last "worst" way and it didn't work, I edited the question to include what I tried using that method and what I got

Comment: Yeah, I think the class name you want to use is "star" -- you want to iterate the <i> elements right? Try that; let's see what happens.

Comment: The thing I am missing in your question is the relationship between the "star" list, which you want to get the value of, and "coach id" -- here's where a more complete code example would be useful!

Comment: Yes, I will try to update the answer right now

Comment: I updated the answer to include the for loop, now as you can see I'm dynamically creating that block of html for as many coaches as I have in my database. Each iteration corresponds to a new block and a coach in my database with a unique id, the value of the id specific to each coach exists in the corresponding <input>. I want to update the rating in the database and to do that I need the coach's id alongside the new rating I'm updating with.